# Jquery + jqueryui - focusing on text field not working for FireFox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, focus, jquery-events

I'm trying to select a text field inside the tab, when the tab is clicked.
The jqueryui event is correctly bound - have tested by putting alerts & by replacing `focus()` in the below code with `hide()`.
But when I say `focus()`, it does not focus inside the text field.
This is for Firefox 3.6.10.
Code as below -

```
  $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
      console.log("ui.panel: " + ui.panel.id);
      var tabName = ui.panel.id;
      $("#" + tabName).children("#pointContainer").children('#pointSearchPointForm').children("#searchAndPoint").focus();
});
```

HTML as below -

```
<div id="tabs-2">
  <DIV id="pointContainer" class="pointContainer">
     <FORM id="pointSearchPointForm" name="pointSearchPointForm" METHOD=POST ACTION="">
        <INPUT size="45" TYPE="text" NAME="searchAndPoint" id="searchAndPoint">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" VALUE="Point Select" ONCLICK="someFunction()">
     </FORM>
  </DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you just call `$("#searchAndPoint").focus();` ? It's an `ID` and supposed to be unique. If it's not unique, then that maybe the prblem.

Comment: The ID is unique, but it doesn't work. The above is a sample code, once it works I'll add logic for the other tabs.

Comment: I can't tell, by the looks of your codes, that should be fine. try `setTimeout()` when you trigger `.focus()`,  let see if it gets it.

Comment: Reigel ! Thanks ! That worked. I have tried setTimeOut in similar situations, but it has never worked, especially with IE. But it worked this time 8-)